L2 gain of an LTI discrete-time system with complex matrices
Consider the system
$$\begin{cases}
&x_{k+1} =A x_k+B u_k \\
&y_k=Cx_k+D u_k
\end{cases} $$
where matrices $(A, B, C, D)$ have complex entries. How can I compute (or upper bound) the $L_2$ gain of this system? Can I still use the standard LMIs that are valid for real systems?

Can you point to a reference for the standard LMI's that apply to real systems? Probably the easiest thing to do here is to look through the derivation, and see if anything would change for a complex system. My guess is probably not (except that any transposes should be conjugate-transposes instead)

The same conditions hold but with conjugate transposes and a Hermitian matrix $P$.

The $L_2$-gain of the given complex-valued linear discrete-time system is less than $\gamma$ if and only if there exists a positive definite Hermitian matrix $P=P^*$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A^*PA-P+C^*C & A^*PB+C^*D\\
B^*PA+D^*C & B^*PB+D^*D-\gamma^2I
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is negative definite.
There is no major difference with the real case.
